# C# isPowerOf function

Tags: c#, math, exponentiation

I have the next function:

```
static bool isPowerOf(int num, int power)
{
        double b = 1.0 / power;
        double a = Math.Pow(num, b);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        return a == (int)a;
}
```

I inserted the print function for analysis.

If I call the function:

```
isPowerOf(25, 2)
```

It return true since `5^2` equals 25.
But, if I call 16807, which is `7^5`, the next way:

```
isPowerOf(16807, 5)
```

In this case, it prints '7' but `a == (int)a` return false.

Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: Obligatory link to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Everyone's going to suggest better floating point comparisons, but IMO the root of the problem is the algorithm here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a small epsilon for rounding errors:

```
return Math.Abs(a - (int)a) < 0.0001;
```

As harold suggested, it will be better to round in case `a` happens to be slightly smaller than the integer value, like 3.99999:

```
return Math.Abs(a - Math.Round(a)) < 0.0001;
```

Comment: @GuyDavid: Its because of rounding errors, the number you got isn't 7, but it is 7.000000001 or something like that

Comment: @Guy David try : Console.WriteLine((int)a);

Comment: What if the result of math.pow is off by more than 0.0001?

Comment: @harold: it shouldn't be, rounding errors are usually at a constant point if you make a single calculation.

Comment: @Dani maybe so, but this still breaks. For example, for `num = 4*4*4` `pow = 3`, you get `a = 3.9999999999999996` which is *truncated down*, with a difference of nearly one. Should probably be a round rather than a truncate.

Answer (score 5):

Comparisons that fix the issue have been suggested, but what's actually the problem here is that *floating point should not be involved at all*. You want an exact answer to a question involving integers, not an approximation of calculations done on inherently inaccurate measurements.

So how else can this be done?

The first thing that comes to mind is a cheat:

```
double guess = Math.Pow(num, 1.0 / power);
return num == exponentiateBySquaring((int)guess, power) ||
       num == exponentiateBySquaring((int)Math.Ceil(guess), power);
       // do NOT replace exponentiateBySquaring with Math.Pow
```

It'll work as long as the `guess` is less than 1 off. But I can't guarantee that it will always work for your inputs, because that condition is not always met.

So here's the next thing that comes to mind: a binary search (the variant where you search for the upper boundary first) for the `base` in `exponentiateBySquaring(base, power)` for which the result is closest to `num`. If and only if the closest answer is equal to `num` (and they are both integers, so this comparison is clean), then `num` is a `power`-th power. Unless there is overflow (there shouldn't be), that should always work.

Comment: Yes indeedy, there are good reasons why integers and floating-point numbers are separate types.

Answer (score 2):

If you debug the code and then you can see that in first comparison:

```
isPowerOf(25, 2)
```

a is holding `5.0`
Here 5.0 == 5 => that is why you get true

and in 2nd `isPowerOf(16807, 5)`

a is holding `7.0000000000000009`

and since `7.0000000000000009 != 7` => you are getting false. and Console.WriteLine(a) is truncating/rounding the double and only show 7

That is why you need to compare the nearest value like in Dani's solution

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Pow` operates on `double`s, so rounding errors come into play when taking roots. If you want to check that you've found an exact power:

- perform the `Math.Pow` as currently, to extract the root
- **round** the result to the nearest integer
- raise this integer to the supplied power, and check you get the supplied target. `Math.Pow` will be exact for numbers in the range of `int` when raising to integer powers